# File Locations via Windows Explorer

Tags: video

I have a video (.mp4) downloaded on a phone that I want to watch on my desktop computer, but I am unable to access it from my PC. I know that I can access hidden folders by typing the file location; for example, if I type in the address bar computer\windows phone\phone\music\playlists, I can view playlists that I have created even though the playlist folder is hidden. Does anyone know the path to reach the download folder and/or the program files folder?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you download it? Via the browser or app? If browser did it open an app?

Comment: It all depends on what you used to download the video. I don't believe IE lets you download videos but UC Browser does.

Comment: I used an app to download it; IE wouldn't allow me to.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to access an apps isolated storage. That's why it's called an isolated storage.

Later on it might be possible but it isn't right now.